# Plotting degree distribution with fit

Tags: matlab, distribution, graph-theory, data-fitting

This might be a conceptual problem (if so, please tell me the forum to use, I'll ask it there), but I'm really stuck on this.

I want to plot a degree distribution in Matlab and a fit to the data. I suspect the degree distribution to agree to a power-law distribution from some `xmin` (minimal value) on. So first I have my degree array:

```
s=[2 3 4 4 5 4 4 4 5 6 4 3 5 6 7 5 etc];
```

I calculate the probability distribution, where I am taking bins from 1 to 10:

```
ps=hist(s,1:10)
```

Subsequently I can plot this by using

```
loglog(ps)
```

which does indicate that the node degree follows a power-law distribution from node degree=4 onwards.

For the fit I am using `plfit` (developed by the Santa Fe Institute, see [here](http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/powerlaws/)) to estimate the exponential component `alpha` and minimal value for which the power-law behaviour holds `xmin`. Now I the main thing is that I am having trouble plotting this fit to the data, it seems as if I am missing something. At the moment I am doing this to visualise the plot:

```
x=1:1:10;
pfit=x.^-alpha;
loglog(pfit)
```

Which results in
[image]

which is a lot more poor than expected (I would expect it to be very close to the data for `x>xmin`).

I hope anyone has any experience with this and would be able to help me out, or even a pointer in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The `ps` that you calculate is not the probability. To get the probability distribution you need to normalize it:

```
ps = ps/sum(ps);
```

You probably need to do the same for `pfit`, this however might be provided by the library you are using.

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the example, but I did normalise the probability distribution. However, the `pfit` was not normalised yet. After normalising this the resulting fit seems a lot worse. Any ideas what other things I might be doing wrong?